# CefBrowser offset render when first loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Attached is a screenshot as well as the code.  There isn't much of it.
When I first open the window, everything is rendered with an offset.
If I close the window and reopen it, it renders correctly the second time.

```
public partial class frmTwinklyLogin : Form
{
    public ChromiumWebBrowser webBrowser;
    public frmTwinklyLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeBrowser();
    }

    private void frmTwinklyLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void InitializeBrowser()
    { 
        webBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://api.twinkly.com/v2/auth/login?response_type=code&client_id=omen-hp-client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8487/login");
        webBrowser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;


        this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
        webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webBrowser.Refresh();
    }
    private void Browser_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = e.Address;
        if (x.Contains("code="))
        {
            var code = x.Split('=')[1];    
            TwinklyWebApi.SetCode(code);
        }
    }
}
```

and the initialization of the library is in application load.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

I can only assume I've got something in the wrong event.  Either that or my monitor dpi is screwing with it.  Note:  It's merely rendered off-center.  The click areas for the controls are still where they are supposed to be, which makes the page unusable.
[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#high-dpi-displayssupport

Comment: Thanks.  I had already seen something similar but it only listed the answer for older versions of .net.  Adding something to my app.config fixed it.

Comment: Naturally enabling it broke something else in my app though.  I have a grid area i draw on with graphics effects and I had to jump through hoops to get the scale factor and multiply my points so they still drew in the correct locations.

Comment: For reference WinForms has methods for scaling see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.logicaltodeviceunits?view=windowsdesktop-6.0